# In DOTA 2 how do you create a "level up ability" hotkey

Tags: dota-2

I'm new to dota but have played quite a bit of league of legends and I'm very much used to using ctrl-qwer to level up my abilities. Is there a way to do this in dota 2?

Comment: Control+QWER. Set 'attribute learn' to something for stats; I use Z.

Comment: Unfortunately despite what possible key remapping you do on OS X mac it seems command skill key is what seems to be used.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not a very experienced player but I just opened up Dota 2 and tried mapping 'Ability Learn' to control and it didn't work.

However, upon a little bit of research and testing to verify if what [this site](http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=19673) says is true, it seems that what you're asking is hard-coded into the game, and that's why you can't change the key binding for control through the options menu.

So basically: ctrl+(ability key) DOES level up your ability, without needing any changes in your settings.

Comment: Well that was easy, I tried it in the tutorial and it didn't work but just tried it in a bot game and it worked, thanks.

Comment: @amccaffrey The tutorial only letts you get a specific ability iirc.